# How to configure PL/SQL Developer IDE to leave the columns names as they are?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have created a table with some columns using PL/SQL Develper to access this Oracle database.

After clicking the "Apply" button that will create the table, all my column names suddenly become upper case (which can hardly be read), including the table name!

Would that be possible to configure PL/SQL Developer IDE to leave the columns names and table names as they are?!

Comment: oracle dictionary works in uppercase letters. the naming convention for object in oracle is usually to separate words by "_". for example `PRODUCT_TYPE`

Comment: @haki, where did you get that idea? The oracle dictionary doesn't "work in uppercase letters", it allows the full range of valid identifiers including upper and lowercase letters.

Comment: Oracle defaults to storing tablenames in the data dictionary in uppercase. If you just specify a tablename without quotes in a SQL command it will be converted to uppercase. If you enclose a table or column name in double quotes then it will be used as is.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp - i accept your comment but working this way will cause much more harm than good.

Comment: @haki, I was responding to your strange assertion that the "oracle dictionary works in uppercase letters". There is no such restriction in oracle. In fact, it would indicate an oracle bug if there was!

Answer (score 2):

You can give column name in double quote "". Then those column name will be in as it is.

Comment: You can force them to lower case but this is dangerous. It is possible in oracle to create a table... 

    create table "MY_TABLE" (...);

and... 

    create table "My_Table" (...);

and... 

    create table "My_TaBlE" (...);

All at the same time!

If you don't have the "" Oracle forces them to upper to ensure there is only one MY_TABLE.

It might be hard to read but it's less confusing than having multiple tables with the same name but different case characters.

Comment: you are right @Dave. But one more thing I don't feel any difficulty while reading table name in upper case. what you say?
while giving the table name you can give underscore '_' for separating words and this will help also while writing query.. as I believe.

Comment: I agree (as you can see from my example MY_TABLE) that is exactly what I do. I also tend to write my own create table rather than using SQLDEV to do it for me so if coding standards are `create table thisIsMyTable` then I can do that. It's only when using the wizards that SQLDEV forces them to upper case.

Comment: correct.. but well .. @The light has his question.. may be this is required for his certain situation. so this thing he can use for getting out of the trouble .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle DBMS ignores case and translates everything to uppercase *unless* you use quotes. But the quotes have the liability that you always have to use them.

[image: Create Table with Quotes]

[image: Select Table with Quotes]

If you do not use the quotes you will get an error message ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Can you see them now? I revised my whole answer anyways.